# Изъятие значения QspinBox из сигнала

Tags: c++, qt

Накануне делаю простенькое приложение, а именно график на кривые Лиссажу. Почти все сделал, но остаётся маленькая загвоздка.

```
class LissageFunction : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    LissageFunction(QObject *obj = 0);
    void setFunction(double wa, double wy, double w1, double w2);

    double getWx();
    double getWy();
    double getW1();
    double getW2();

    void setFunctionInPoints();
    QVector<QPointF> getFunctionInPoints();
private:
    double Wx;
    double Wy;
    double W1;
    double W2;

    QVector<QPointF> function;
public slots:
    void setValueWx(double wx){ this->Wx = wx; emit changeFunction()};//пример
    void setValueWy(double);
    void setValueW1(double);
    void setValueW2(double);
signals:
    void changeFunction();
};
```

В общем, есть класс на кривые лиссажу, отдельный виджет, который представляет координатную сетку и 4 отдельных QSpinBox-кса для параметров Wx, Wy, W1, W2 - которые как предполагается должны регулировать эти уравнения:

> x(t) = sin(Wx * t + W1); 
>   y(t) = sin(Wy * t + W2);

Я, допустим регулирую значения и посылаю сигнал

```
QSpinBox *Wx = new QSpinBox;
connect(Wx,SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),LissageFunction,SLOT(setValueWx(double)));
```

(далее в теории я просто высылаю сигнал об изменении значения, и слот из виджета графика перерисовывает из переопределенной функции paintEvent;)

Я не до конца понимаю механизм сигналов и слотов, а из учебника Шлее слишком примитивные или готовые примеры их взаимодействия между виджетами.

Я правильно понимаю, что нужно отдельно наследовать Спинбоксы и определять свои сигналы для моего класса или сигнал valueChanged(int) как-то неявно передает слоту значение? Если да, то как обработать его в сигнале setValueWx(double), чтобы изменить значение переменной

Comment: Сигнал `valueChanged(int)` вполне явно передает значение в параметре

Comment: Да, все верно, они передаются явно)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел одно решение, чтобы понять, от какого сигнала спинбокса пришло значение и изъять его значение, можно этой строкой

```
int x = ((QSpinBox*)sender())->value();
```

В описываемом слоте.

P.S значения в сигналах передаются слоту явно, поэтому можно обрабатывать прямо из параметра слота без выше написанной функции. А так же, что бы сигнал и слот имел исключительно одинаковый тип, без int -> double, как это было у меня.